# Break MySQL row examination with primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider:

```
id int(primary key , unique)   
status enum('enable','disable')   
round tinyint(1) (index)  
core tinyint(1) (index)  
timestamp int(10) (index)
```

I got a query in a table with about 1,800,000 rows. There's a query like:

```
SELECT *  
FROM  tblmatch 
WHERE status = 'disable' 
  and round=0 
  AND core = 3 
  AND time_stamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
ORDER BY time_stamp ASC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Row examination of the query is about 1,680,000 rows.

So, I added `id > 1600000` condition to the query, so it looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblmatch 
WHERE id > 1600000 
  AND status = 'disable' 
  and round=0 
  AND time_stamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
ORDER BY time_stamp ASC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Yet, row examinations are the same. Is there a way to break the row examination?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*row examinations"? This is not a common term in the "database world".

Comment: Is the id starting from 1?I don't see any autoincrement.Post some sample data.

Comment: actually it logs in my **slow query log** and it takes 6-10 seconds. the row examinations is also there !

Comment: PEACE, can you elaborate on what "row examination" is?

Comment: Full `SHOW CREATE TABLE` & `EXPLAIN` output is more useful then you summarizing it. Can you share those? Also, a `SHOW INDEXES FROM tablename`  might help with the cardinality of indexes. On a side note: having 1.8M rows, and then assuming a > 1.6M id will only select the top of it, might not be true. It depends on what the actial `id`'s are.